# Reduce representation of $SL_n$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $a$ be an arbitrary element of $SL_n$. Consider next representation of $SL_n$. $T_a: SL_n \to GL_n,\;x \mapsto axa^{-1}$. I was told that this is a reducible representation. So I need to express this representation as a sum of irreducible ones. I've read that I need to find an invariant subspaces of this representation. And this is the part where I stucked.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $T_a$ meant to be a map from and to?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft edited the question

Comment: The adjoint action is a map $SL_n\to \text{Aut}(\mathfrak{sl}_n)$, so the map $T_a$ should be $\mathfrak{sl}_n \to \mathfrak{sl}_n$.

Comment: @itinerantleopard well, I think I misunderstood this term. Will edit my question.

Comment: There is a result that says, for matrix Lie groups (for example, $SL_n$), the adjoint action acts by conjugation: $T_a: (g \mapsto gXg^{-1})$, however you have to be careful, as $g\in SL_n$ and $X\in  \mathfrak{sl}_n$ live in different spaces! In order to multiply them as matrices, we have to identify identify elements of $\mathfrak{sl}_n:= T_{\text{Id}}(SL_n)$ with matrices, which we do by embedding the tangent spaces of $SL_n$ into the tangent spaces of $GL_n$ via the derivative of the inclusion map $SL_n\hookrightarrow GL_n$.

Comment: @itinerantleopard So I mention wrong map? Btw how to factorize(?) this representation?

Comment: To start, it will be useful to figure out what matrices in $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ look like (i.e. find a defining condition). Just as an aside, you should keep in mind that just because a representation is reducible doesn't mean it is *completely reducible* (i.e. it doesn't mean you can write it as a direct sum of irreducibles). It is quite possible to have an invariant subspace (i.e. a subrepresentation) without a complementary subrepresentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83336/discussion-between-kirill-losev-and-itinerantleopard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find two invariant subspaces: $<E>$ and $A=\{M\in Mat_{n\times n} : trM=0\}$.
It's easy to see that $V=<E> \oplus A$. Now we need to show that there is no proper invariant subspace in A. So we find a highest weight vector: $\begin{bmatrix}0*0 1\\ 0*00\\0*00\\0*00\end{bmatrix}$. As there is only one highest weight vector, there exist only one invariant subspace, which is our A.